# Center the content of CommandBar (XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I would like to be able to center the content of my CommandBar. My current code is this

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="BottomBar"  Background="Black" Visibility="Collapsed" OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed" >

        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="btnSend" Icon="Forward"  Foreground="White"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="btnCancel" Icon="Clear"  Foreground="White"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>

        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Name="tbBar" Text="EOOOOOOOOO" Foreground="White" Margin="12,14" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>

</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

This puts the content on the left and aligned horizontally and vertically but I need it in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written about this on my blog [here](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/01/aligning-uwp-commandbar-content-after-anniversary-update/), so browse it for full detail. The reason for this problem is the `IsDynamicOverflowEnabled` property, which was added in the Anniversary Update. When this is set to enabled, the `Grid` Column the `Content` of the `CommandBar` resides in gets `Width="Auto"`, which means it gives the content only the space it actually needs and reserves all remaining space to the `CommandBar` buttons.

The easiest solution is to set `IsDynamicOverflowEnabled` to false. If you want to keep this feature, you would have to modify the default template of `CommandBar`.

```
<CommandBar HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            IsDynamicOverflowEnabled="False">
   <CommandBar.Content>
      <TextBlock Text="Content" />
   </CommandBar.Content>
</CommandBar>
```